# How to integrate Visual Studio solution build into flutter build system

Tags: flutter, windows, cmake, msbuild

I have a couple of DLL library projects created with Visual Studio. One of them is using C# and the other is using C++/CLI. The library written in C++/CLI provides a C interface to the C# library so it can be called from Dart through FFI.

I would like to create a Flutter plugin using FFI to wrap these libraries into a Dart interface and then use them inside a Flutter app.

I have written all the Dart FFI code, and some CMake code using [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add) calling to `msbuild`. I also found [include_external_msproject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_external_msproject.html), but I could not get it to work.

I have managed to get it working, but I'm not happy with the build system setup. The VS solution is hardcoded to build in Release mode in the CMake script. I would like to do a debug build of the VS project when building the debug version of the flutter application. When I print the value of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, it is empty. I'm not sure how to proceed from here to detect the build type of the Flutter app.

I need to know the build type in the CMake script because the Debug configuration outputs are put in a `Debug` folder, and Release configuration outputs are in the `Release` folder. I need to know whoch folder to use when setting the `my_plugin_bundled_libraries` variable for Flutter.

Is this the right approach to integrate an external VS project? If not, how should I integrate the external project so that it will build correctly in both release and debug builds?

Comment: @LucyZoo Please read the tag descriptions when you retag. [tag:integrate] explicitly says not to use it.